# creating paragraphs in embeds discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to create a paragraph in embeds like this:

```
desc1 = ("
criteria for Youtuber role: 
over 50 subscribers 
upload at least once a month

criteria for Twitch Streamer role: 
Over 50 followers 
stream once a month")
aembed=discord.Embed(title="New @Youtuber and @Twitch Streamer roles", description=(desc1), colour=discord.Color.blue(), url="")
```

not like what I have now:

```
desc1 = ("criteria for Youtuber role: over 50 subscribers, upload at least once a month, criteria for Twitch Streamer role: Over 50 followers, stream once a month")
aembed=discord.Embed(title="New @Youtuber and @Twitch Streamer roles", description=(desc1), colour=discord.Color.blue(), url="")
```

every time I try the first one I get an error message because it is no longer part of the text
I already tried block brackets and commas

Comment: Why are you not inserting it into the description directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using triple quotes should work

```py
desc1 = """
criteria for Youtuber role: 
over 50 subscribers 
upload at least once a month

criteria for Twitch Streamer role: 
Over 50 followers 
stream once a month"""
```

This also works

```py
desc1 = ("criteria for Youtuber role:\n"
         "over 50 subscribers\n"
         "upload at least once a month\n"
         "criteria for Twitch Streamer role:\n"
         "Over 50 followers\n"
         "stream once a month")
```